# Drag and Drop Text Fields AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, drag-and-drop

**I'm trying to make text fields drag-able within Flash using Action script 3**,

I know how to make regular objects drag-able, but the problem occurs when I try to drag a textfield.

For regular objects I have been using the following code:

Event listeners:

```
Object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, MouseDOWN);
Object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUP);
```

Functions:

```
function MouseDOWN(evt:Event):void {
    evt.target.startDrag();
}

function MouseUP(evt:Event):void {
        evt.target.stopDrag();
}
```

I've tried many things such as changing 'target' to 'currentTarget' etc, but still can not find a solution.

**So my question is, how can I make text fields selectable and drag-able?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startDrag();` and `stopDrag();` are methods of the `Sprite` class, and also inherited by `MovieClip`, which is a subclass of `Sprite`

It's a good idea to check the official Adobe documentation to see what classes inherit what methods;

[Sprite class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html)

[TextField class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html)

Because `Sprite` and `MovieClip` are both base classes of the `DisplayObjectContainer` class, the simple solution is to simply store the `TextField` object inside a `Sprite` object using `addChild();`

```
        var textBox:TextField = new TextField;
        textBox.text = "sometext";
        var textContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
        textContainer.addChild(textBox);
        textContainer.startDrag();
        addChild(textContainer);
```

You then have all the functionality of `Sprite` to drag it across the stage.

**Edit:**

Another option would have been to extend the TextField class with your own custom class and implement your own `startDrag()` and `stopDrag()` methods.

You'd then have a public `update()` method that you could call from your main class that would take in the `mouseX`, `mouseY` properties which then sets your object's `x`, `y` properties. You could turn this functionality on and off with a simple `Boolean`.

It's more work, yes, but if for whatever reason you needed to work with `TextField` type objects (for example, if you needed to pass it into another object that required it be of type `TextField`), then your class would also be a type of `TextField` as it inherits it as a base class.

Comment: Solved now, but thanks, that's a good piece of advice, Yeah I was aware it's not possible directly through the TextField class, but knew it was possible some how, I used the method you mentioned about storing it inside a movieclip which worked great.

Comment: @Alex - Glad to hear it meets your requirements. I'm going to add a second alternative option to my answer, just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: ok great, I'll take a look at that some time, Thanks again :)